# Read AzureDevOps Pipeline Variables in C#

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, console-application, azure-pipelines

I need develop a C# .NetCore Console Application to access my DevOps account, select a release and read all variables in Pipeline Variables[[image]

Anybody can give me an example?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If your application needs to access configuration values at runtime, a more common approach is to use a configuration file that's transformed at deployment time or to store configuration in a configuration management service such as Azure KeyVault.

Comment: Agreed, it's unusual to be reaching out to Azure DevOps within an application to pull values from your pipeline variables. @Daniel Mann is correct, if you're looking to store configuration centrally and pull it at runtime, Azure Key Vault is the correct choice in that scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution do read variables from Azure DevOps with REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a rough draft to read the variables from a release definition. You can create the `.NET` helper objects by creating helper classes from the JSON. There are sites on the internet for this.

```cs
Main() {
    var pat = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("????");
    var baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}";
    var apiversion = "api-version=6.0";
    var project = "????";
    var search = "Releasename";
    var actUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}/_apis/release/definitions?searchText={2}&{3}",baseUrl,project,search,apiversion);   
    var json = await GetJsonFromUrlPAT(actUrl, pat);
    cReleases varReleases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cReleases>(json);
    int ReleaseId=0;

    if (varReleases.count == 1)
    {
        ReleaseId = varReleases.values[0].id;
        actUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}/_apis/release/definitions/{2}?{3}",baseUrl,project,ReleaseId,apiversion);
        var json2 = await GetJsonFromUrlPAT(actUrl, pat);
        cReleasedefinition varReleaseDef = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cReleasedefinition>(json2);
        string jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(varReleaseDef);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String,JToken> element in varReleaseDef.variables)
        {
            string varname = element.Key;
            string varvalue = ((JObject)(element.Value)).GetValue("value").ToString();
        }

        foreach (var element in varReleaseDef.environments)
        {
            string environmentname = element.name;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> item in element.variables)
            {
                string varname = item.Key;
                string varvalue = ((JObject)(item.Value)).GetValue("value").ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

No worries!

To get your pipeline variables applied to your application configuration, you're going to want to use the **File Transform** task within your pipeline and configure it to point to your configuration JSON file within the **Target Files**

- File Transform Task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops

[image: Azure DevOps - File Transform Example]

What this task is going to do is use the variables you've associated with your pipeline to replace values within your JSON configuration.

Some things to note when using **File Transform:**

- It can only perform **replace** operations, it cannot **add** to your configuration. So, be sure to have placeholders for every value you are looking to replace within your JSON file.
- To access a nested value within JSON, you want to use a period within your naming conventions. In your case for example, **you'll want to change ConnectionStrings:StorageAccountLogs** to **ConnectionStrings.StorageAccountLogs" ** in order to correctly perform the variable substitution.

Comment: This **does not** answer the question. The question is about how to read variables *from* Azure DevOps *in* a C# application.